# With $xy+yz+zx=-1$, proving: $x^2+2y^2+2z^2 .....$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Assuming $xy+yz+zx=-1$, prove that :

> $$x^2+2y^2+2z^2 \geq \frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Consider editing you question

Comment: Do you know about Lagrange Multiplier?

Comment: @thannhantrung211:whats x,y, z they are real number or not? define them

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo isnt it safe to assume they're real?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by suitable coefficients and a variant of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

First, note that $\dfrac{a_1^2}{b_1} + \dfrac{a_2^2}{b_2} + \dfrac{a_3^2}{b_3} \ge \dfrac{(a_1 + a_2 + a_3)^2}{b_1 + b_2+b_3}$.  This readily follows from Cauchy Schwarz, for real numbers $a_i$ and $b_i$.

So, $\dfrac{x^2}{a} + \dfrac{y^2}{b} + \dfrac{z^2}{b} \ge \dfrac{(x + y + z)^2}{a + 2b} = \dfrac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2}{a + 2b}$

$$ \implies \left( \frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{a+2b} \right)x^2 + \left( \frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{a+2b} \right)\left(y^2+z^2\right) \ge \frac{-2}{a+2b}$$

Comparing with the LHS we want in our equality, we have two equations to solve to get the right $a, b$ :
$$ \frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{a+2b} = 1 \text{ and } \frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{a+2b} = 2$$

Solving these, you have two possible solutions, choose the one which gives you the desired  RHS.

In this case, $b = \dfrac{7+\sqrt{17}}{8} $ and $a = -\dfrac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2} $ do the trick and give RHS of $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2} $

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that
$$x^2+2y^2+2z^2+\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}(xy+xz+yz)\geq0$$ or
$$x^2+\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}(y+z)x+2y^2+2z^2+\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}yz\geq0,$$
for which it's enough to prove that
$$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}(y+z)\right)^2-4\left(2y^2+2z^2+\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}yz\right)\leq0,$$
which is $(y-z)^2\geq0$.

Done!